# How to solve SSL Version\Cipher mismatch error after Jetty web server upgrade?

Tags: ssl, jetty, hsts

I upgraded Jetty server version in my application from `9.3.6.v20151106` to `9.4.6.v20170531`. This was done to get the [HSTS support](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/271) and other possible improvements.

However, after I did the changes I am not able to launch my application's UI and I get the error "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" in chrome (60.0.3112.113) while "SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP" in Firefox (55.0.3 (32-bit)).

While in Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.18697) it launches correctly!

What is it that I am missing about Jetty Server upgrade to make it work on all browsers?

**Update**

I checked the debug output of class `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory` and it is huge. Here is the summary:

It selects `TLS 1.2` with both Jetty versions. It selects `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` with Jetty `9.3.6` version whereas with Jetty `9.4.6` its selection reduces to `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`. This is strange because we are setting all four ciphers with the setter methods for both Jetty versions.

Why is it rejecting to set the other two?

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging on `org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory` and report back the includes/excludes it reports on your protocols and ciphers (for both Jetty 9.3.6 and 9.4.6)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added the output summary to the description above.

Comment: Can I see how you are "setting all four ciphers with setter methods".

Comment: Note that the 9.4.6 output tells you why specific protocols and ciphers are excluded.

Comment: Any solution yet?